# In git for-each-ref, what is the difference between %(refname) and %(upstream:remoteref)?

Tags: git

When using the `--format` option in `git for-each-ref`, what is the difference between the `%(refname)` and `%(upstream:remoteref)`?

In all my Git repos, whenever `%(upstream:remoteref)` is non-empty it is always equal to the `%(refname)`. Is there some situation where they may be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track any remote branch from any local branch :

```
# from local branches feature/poc :
git branch -u origin/develop
# now typing 'git pull' will merge remote 'develop' into your local branch
```

Comment: You can track any branch at all from any local branch.

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout -tb myfeature origin/master
```

and your new feature branch will merge from/rebase on `origin/master`, whose upstream ref is in all likelihood `refs/heads/master`. You'll do this for instance when you're creating a new branch for the first time.